# Googlesheets: joining multiple cells from multiple rows into one unique cell for each row

Tags: google-sheets-formula, row, formula, spreadsheet, textjoin

I’m working on a kanban board. So I want the kanban board to display elements from the dataset based on the condition of its `Status` (`1` and `2`, or really anything else like `To do` and `Done`).

I want the Kanban board to display all the elements present in the row (`Task` and `Assignee`) in one single cell **for each row** in the dataset.

I have the following table:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Task 1 | Assignee 1 | Status 1 |
| Task 2 | Assignee 2 | Status 1 |
| Task 3 | Assignee 3 | Status 3 |

I have the following formula:

```
=(TEXTJOIN(","; TRUE; QUERY(DATA!$A:$C;"SELECT * WHERE C='Status 1'")))
```

This works well, except that it concatenates the two rows into one unique cell. What I am looking for is rather to have the values of the two rows being into their unique cell, dependent on the `Status`’s status (`1` or `2`).

In other words, it gives me that:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task 1 | Assignee 1 | Status 1 | Task 1, Assignee 1, Task 2, Assignee 2 |
| Task 2 | Assignee 2 | Status 1 |  |
| Task 3 | Assignee 3 | Status 3 |  |

But what I want is:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task 1 | Assignee 1 | Status 1 | Task 1, Assignee 1 |
| Task 2 | Assignee 2 | Status 1 | Task 2, Assignee 2 |
| Task 3 | Assignee 3 | Status 3 |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different formula option you can try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="Status 1",A2:A & ", " & B2:B,))
```

Or try this formula:

```
=BYROW(query(A2:C,"select A,B where C='Status 1'"),LAMBDA(row, JOIN(", ",row))).
```

This will give you a column with all the results in consecutive rows with no blank rows in between if that is more what is desired.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn’t clear. I edited it. The `Status` needs to be included in the query, as it is the main condition to display the rest of the elements. Please see the revised question for a clearer idea.

Comment: I have also modified my answer.  Perhaps give the new formula a try...

Comment: I have provided a second solution which may be more in line with what you are looking for.

Comment: The second did work for me, thank you! Can you just give a quick explanation about the Lambda function ?

Comment: From [Google Support](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?sjid=3896468889048685191-NA).  Worth reading the documentation and playing around with some of their example formulas.

Answer (score 1):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=filter(A:A&", "&B:B,C:C="Status 1")
```

[image]

Comment: This may work best with just a few columns indeed, but if I have more columns, then it becomes quickly burdensome to manually add them. With the query, it’s quite straight forward, no?

Comment: then something like this should work out: `=filter(byrow(A:B,lambda(Σ,join(", ",Σ))),C:C="Status 1")`

Comment: Is it better to use filter than query?